# Vlookup Change Event in array and dictionary

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I want to make vba vlookup change event with array and dictionary so that the process becomes fast because the record data is twenty-five thousand. Sheet "master" is the data source sheet and I mark the yellow color of the result that appears in the transaction sheet ("TRANS") and the sheet "trans" is the transaction sheet and which I mark the yellow color comes from the data source of the sheet "MASTER" My green marking is key or unique id. if I use the formula "vlookup" very slowly So I want a vba code with dictionary & array?
if I change in the "master" sheet example in the "item desc" column can it change directly to the "Trans" sheet?
so need eventhandler in sheet "master"?

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 'On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit

    If Intersect(Target, Range("L:L")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim fnd As Range
    Set fnd = Sheets("MASTER").Range("B:B").Find(Target, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not fnd Is Nothing Then

Target.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 1).Value = Array(fnd.Offset(, 3))
Target.Offset(, 4).Resize(, 1).Value = Array(fnd.Offset(, 6))
Target.Offset(, 6).Resize(, 1).Value = Array(fnd.Offset(, 8))
Target.Offset(, 7).Resize(, 1).Value = Array(fnd.Offset(, 4))

    End If
'bm_Safe_Exit:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image: SHEER "MASTER"]
[image: SHEET "TRANS"]

Comment: `Match()` is much faster than `Find()`   What's the problem with the code you posted though?

Comment: `Target.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 1).Value = Array(fnd.Offset(, 3))` is the same with `Target.Offset(, 2).Value = fnd.Offset(, 3).value`. No any gain in using an array in such a way. Only iteration in an array containing more elements, being done in memory, makes the code faster. Does your code return anything each time? If  not, the above suggestion is the key of the problem. If you change anything in another column, starting from that moment all events do not work, anymore.

Comment: Please, comment the line `On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit`. You should use it **only after you are sure that the code does not return errors**. This part of the code: `....Value = Array(fnd.Offset(, 3))` should return an error, I think, but you cannot see it because of the error handling way.

Comment: @TimWilliams ,The first code is slow to record data that is thousands, secondly if I do copy 5 different codes the results are not appropriate.

Comment: @FaneDuru , So how does the solution work quickly for thousands of records? Can you use dictionary?

Comment: @FaneDuru , Ok I've uncommented at your request

Comment: @chrisneilsen , Well I move according to the request from you

Comment: A dictionary will not be of any help, I think. Try using `Match` instead of `Find`. As stated in a previous comment, it is faster. Arrays and dictionaries make code faster only if it is an iteration involved, and in your case it is not. You can do that in the next way: `Dim mtch` `mtch = Application.Match(Target.Value, Sheets("MASTER").Range("B:B"), True)`. Then `If IsNumeric(mtch) Then Target.Offset(, 2).Value = Sheets("MASTER").Range("B" & mtch).offset( ,3).value` and so on...

Comment: @TimWilliams , I've tried the code from you, I tried copying the code twenty-eight thousand but it is still slow and also causes not responding. Another one if the code in one line I deleted in the sheet "TRANS" then it should be blank

Comment: If commenting on a posted answer it's useful to add the comment below the answer...  It's not clear really what you're doing here.  `Worksheet_Change` isn't really designed for high-volume updates: are you copy-pasting 28k id's into Col L on TRANS ?  That's going to take some time to complete if only because there are a lot of individual cells which have to be updated.   Try turning off screenupdating and calculation while the updates are being made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be faster:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, m, wsM As Worksheet, arr
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("L:L"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Set wsM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MASTER")
    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Screenupdating  = False           'improve performance...
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For Each c In rng.Cells    'process all changed cells in ColB
        v = c.Value
        If len(v) > 0 Then
            m = Application.Match(c.Value, wsM.Range("B:B"), 0) 'match much faster than Find()
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                arr = wsM.Cells(m, "E").Resize(1, 6) 'one read
                c.Offset(0, 2).Value = arr(1, 1)
                c.Offset(0, 4).Value = arr(1, 4)
                c.Offset(0, 6).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(arr(1, 6), arr(1, 2))
            End If
        Else
            c.Entirerow.Range("N1,P1,R1:S1").ClearContents 'clear cells if no code
        End If
    Next c

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True   'be sure to re-enable events
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'reset calculation
End Sub
```

Comment: It goes perfectly and slowly becomes reduced. But there is one thing I would like to ask if I change in the "master" sheet example in the "item desc" column can it change directly to the "Trans" sheet?

Comment: You’d need another event handler in the Master sheet for that…

Comment: @@TimWilliams ,Can you add in the answer to the eventhandler code in the sheet "Master"?

Comment: Why don't you try writing it first?  All the components are there - you just have to swap things around.

Comment: ,or I make a new post but can you help me?

Comment: I've added a question in my post

Comment: need eventhandler in sheet "master"?

Comment: I've mark solution to your answer, sorry I'm late and I have the latest post maybe you can help.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71007945/want-to-change-formula-to-vba-array-and-dictionary)