# want to change formula to vba array and dictionary

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I want to convert the formula to vba array and dictionary because there are 100000 records and it's also faster. In the "Master" sheet in T and U column it is the result of the formula that I marked in yellow and comes from the source sheet "DB SALES" in the Q column

Thanks
roy

[image: sheet "master"]

[image: sheet "DB SALES"]

```
Sub Lookup99()
Dim V
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheets("MASTER").Range("T2:T" & Sheets("MASTER").UsedRange.Rows.Count)
       .Formula = "=LOOKUP(9^9,DB_SALES[DATE]/(DB_SALES[ITEM NO]=[@[ITEM NO]]),DB_SALES[HB NET])"
        V = .Value
End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

```
 Sub Lookup05()
 Dim V
       With Sheets("MASTER").Range("U2:U" & Sheets("MASTER").UsedRange.Rows.Count)
       .Formula = "=LOOKUP([@Date]+0.5,DB_SALES[DATE]/(DB_SALES[ITEM NO]=[@[ITEM NO]]),DB_SALES[HB NET])"
        V = .Value
End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the LOOKUP formula, so maybe you can explain what each formula is doing?

Comment: @TimWilliams , `LOOKUP(9^9` search for a value based on the last date of the data source and `LOOKUP([@Date]+0.5` search for a value with a transaction date based on the date from the data source

Comment: @FaneDuru , 
maybe you can help me?